# Why does unique_ptr have an overload for auto_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, auto-ptr

I got a compiler error and noticed something interesting. For some reason `unique_ptr` has an overload for `auto_ptr`, but I thought `auto_ptr` was deprecated:

```
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:228:2: 
note:template<class _Up, class> 
std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::auto_ptr<_Up>&&)
  unique_ptr(auto_ptr<_Up>&& __u) noexcept;

/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:228:2: 
note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:41:67: note:  mismatched types 'std::auto_ptr<T>' and 'char*'
```

Is this because of backwards compatibility with code that used `auto_ptr`?

Comment: In addition to backwards compatibility with code that uses `auto_ptr`, it also serves as a transition tool to move from `auto_ptr` to `unique_ptr`.  One doesn't have to transition an entire code base at once.  You can do so a piece at a time, using this conversion to move across the transition boundary.  That being said, field reports have indicated a good success rate at just doing a global search/replace and then investigating compile-time failures, as the method of transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's for interop with auto_ptr, and deprecated means (according to the standard)

> Normative for the current edition of the Standard, but not guaranteed
>   to be part of the Standard in future revisions.